# Javascript property get and set similar to c# .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to functionality something similar to get property of C# .net. for example

```
var method   :   function() {
      return "something which always change";
 },
var objectName = {
 property :   method()
```

};

so whenever i call objectName.property this should return the actual new values. not the value set at the time of declaration. is it possible.

In .net property hold the function address and that function get called each time. i want the functionality like that.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

other way to write this in more like a .net c# style is

```
  var o = {
  a: 7,
  get b() { 
    return this.a + 1;
  },
  set c(x) {
    this.a = x / 2
  }
};
console.log(o.a); // 7
console.log(o.b); // 8
o.c = 50;
console.log(o.a); // 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to override the getter.

```
var counter = 0; 

var method = function() {
   return counter++;
};

function ObjectName() {}

Object.defineProperty(ObjectName.prototype, 'property', {
  get: method
});

var objectName = new ObjectName();

console.log(objectName.property); // 0
console.log(objectName.property); // 1
```

**JSBin Demo https://jsbin.com/racegeteni/edit?js,console**

Comment: thanks, i was looking for this..if you know even better or simpler way of doing this..do post it here...thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

For `OOP` reasons, you should treat an `object` as a `Class` in .Net.

For example:

```js
var Superman = function () {
  
  this.quality = 'charming';
  this.height = "6'5\"";

  this.fly = function() {
    console.log('flying..');

  }

  this.save = function(name) {
    console.log('Save ' + name);
  }
  
  return this;
};

var CK = Superman();

console.log(CK.quality);

CK.save('L. Lane');
```